# Write to the output between two pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipe, echo

I'm trying to write to the output (echo) within two pipe to have a trace of what I'm doing but I have an error.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '.+?\.log\.(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$' -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $deleteDate } |
    Write-Output "deleting file" -PassThru |
    Remove-Item
```

but I have this error :

> Write-Output : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

I also tested in the Foreach-Object function

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |
Where-Object { $_.Name -match '.+?\.log\.(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$' -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $deleteDate } |
Foreach-Object {
    echo "deleting $($_.Name)";
    Remove-Item($_);
}
```

but here nothing is printed in the console (but the script finish without error and deleted the files I wanted)

So how can I print to thje output wihtin two Pipe ?

Thx

Comment: That probably means the condition in your `where` is not true for any file?

Comment: @marsze the condition is correct.The script works well when I remove the "Write-Output pipe"

Comment: In the 2nd script either use `$_ | Remove-Item` or in the 1st insert  `| Tee-Object -Variable Deleted |` instead of Write-Output and later output `$Deleted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Write-Output** sends output to the pipeline. It accepts input via pipeline or argument, but not both, so you can do this:

```
Write-Output "Test"
```

or this:

```
"Test" | Write-Output
```

but **not** this:

```
"Test" | Write-Output "Test"
```

**Solution:**

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | where {
    $_.Name -match '.+?\.log\.(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$' -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $deleteDate
} | foreach {
    # Write-Host writes to the console only
    Write-Host "Deleting $($_.Name)"
    Remove-Item $_
}
```

*Mind that **Remove-Item** expects a string argument, so everything you pass will be converted to string. Casting a `FileInfo` object to string might not always return the full path (because of its implementation of `ToString()`) depending on how it was created!*

In the example above, it is safe to use, but this for instance will **throw an an exception** (if your current working directory is not `$path`):

```
(Get-Item $path).GetFiles() | foreach { Remove-Item $_ }
```

So it's always safest to use `$_.FullName`.

Comment: thx for your reply. About `Remove-Item`, apparently it can deal with $_ alone. No need to specify the fullName.

Comment: @Zou That's only partly true. I've updated my answer to be more clear.